# Horizontal footer navigation in Wordpress

Tags: html, css

This is the site I am working at: http://www.nickthepromisering.com/about

Now my question is that at the footer the page navigation links are in ***vertical order*** but i want it to be in ***horizontal order***

**Example:**
Now the links are in this order:

```
About
Endorsements
Fan Club
Inquiries
Media
More Team Mates
News
Shop
Videos
Photos
```

I want it to be in this order:

```
About Endorsements Fan Club Inquiries Media More Team Mates News Shop Videos Photos
```

Friends, can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Somdeb Mukherjee

Answer (score 1):

In styles.css, add this:

```
#footer .menu ul li { float: left; }
```

or

```
#footer .menu ul li { display: inline; }
```

You'll likely have to fiddle further with the CSS to get it looking good, but either of these will put all of the links on the same line.

Comment: No prob! Mark it as the answer when you get a chance. :)

Comment: FYI: if this is the answer of your question please accept it so that anyone going in this page know this question have already answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard CSS problem. Try something like this:

```
#footer li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Possibly with a different selector if your theme use some other name than `footer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.fcol_pad1 ul li {float:left;margin:0 3px;}
```